# ActiveModel validate attribute based on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations, mongoid, activemodel

I have at least 2 classes.  One class must validate one of its attributes based on the value of an associated model's attributes.  The below code is what I am going for, but its just an idea, it doesn't work.  Any way to achieve it?

```
class Concert
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps

 field :end_date, type: Date
end

class Sale
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :end_date, type: Date

  belongs_to :concert

  validates :end_date, :timeliness => {
        :before => lambda {self.concert.end_date}, 
        :after => lambda {self.concert.created_at}, 
        :before_message => 'Sale should not end before the Concert begins', 
        :after_message => 'Sale should not end after the Concert has already ended',
        :type => :date
    }
end
```

Comment: just a guess, but isn't there a problem with your reference to `self` in your lambdas? I'd go for `=> lambda { |record| record.concert.end_date }`

Comment: you are correct.  the code is just to illustrate what im trying to accomplish, it is not actual working code.  I can just describe what I'm trying to do i code more easily than i can with words.  I will try what you said though.

Comment: Then you should provide real examples so we can give real help ;)

Comment: Cant give real code if i dont know where to begin, which is what the question is about

Comment: You should look at custom validation method, this way you could implement the checks that suits you : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods

Comment: @pduersteler if you answer this with your comment, I'll change accepted answer to yours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a guess, but isn't there a problem with your reference to `self` in your lambdas? I'd go for `=> lambda { |record| record.concert.end_date }`

Answer (score 1):

add validation to Sale

```
validates :end_date, :presence => true, :if => :some_checking

def some_checking
   #your validations
   #eg
   self.concert.end_date.present?
end
```